# Combinations of a set in Java

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

I am trying to give the unique permutations of a set, a.k.a the combinations of a set.

For example, the combinations of the set S={A,B,C} are:

SC={AB, AC, BC}

BA isn't valid as AB=BA, for example.

I tried using tools like the cartesian product but I realized that would be for two sets. I could maybe use it if I did the cartesian product of set S and the same set S, but I think that would be unefficient.

I am trying to obtain triplet combinations, meaning I would like to extend the previous definition to 3 elements instead of 2, which would mean that, intrapolating, I would have tried to use: `if(arr[i] != arr[j] && i !=j)`, but this gives the permutations and not the unique ones. However, I think it is important to first understand 2-element combinations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all subsets of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224953/get-all-subsets-of-a-set)

Comment: @Joe, it does not as it gives even null subsets, but I need the 2-element subsets, for example. Generalizing, I would need the N-element subsets.

Comment: please check leetcode.com tasks - there is something for sure for your case. When you solve, you'll be able to access other people's solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested loop like this:

```
    String[] values = {"A", "B", "C"};
    Set<String> combinations = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
            combinations.add(values[i] + values[j]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(combinations); // [AB, BC, AC]
```

Then with recursion you can adjust it to any number of objects in combination:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int permutationLength = 3;
    String[] values = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    Set<String> combinations = new HashSet<>();
    add(values, permutationLength, 0, new StringBuilder(), combinations);

    System.out.println(combinations); // [ABC, ACD, BCD, ABD]
}

private static void add(String[] allValues, int lettersToAdd, int startingFromIndex, StringBuilder currentPermutation, Set<String> permutationCollector) {
    if (lettersToAdd == 0) {
        permutationCollector.add(currentPermutation.toString());
    }
    for (int i = startingFromIndex; i < allValues.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder permutation = new StringBuilder(currentPermutation.toString());
        permutation.append(allValues[i]);
        add(allValues, lettersToAdd - 1, i + 1, permutation, permutationCollector);
    }
}
```